# CSS table working fine in Google Chrome but not in Mozilla ubuntu

Tags: html, css

How can i make the table fit in screen ? 
[image]

***css***

```
.insert-to-items {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  border-radius: 40px 40px 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgb(230, 0, 0);
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 100%;
  left: 25%;
  margin-left: -330px;
}

.insert-to-items thead tr {
  background-color: #e60000;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.insert-to-items th,
.insert-to-items td {
  padding: 12px 9px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

***html***

```
<table class="insert-to-items">
  <thead>
    <tr>
<th>Item Name</th>
      <th>Prom Name</th>
      <th>Prom Code</th>
      <th>Base Code</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>ΦΠΑ %</th>
      <th>Οικογενεια</th>
      <th>M.M</th>
    </tr>
     </tr>
     <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input size="13" <%= form.text_field :itemName %></td>
        <td><input id="myInput" size="13" <%= form.text_field :prom %></td> 
        <td><input size="13" <%= form.text_field :promCode %></td>
        <td><input size="13" <%= form.text_field :baseCode %></td>
        <td><input size="13" <%= form.text_field :desc %></td>
        <td><input type="number" <%= form.number_field :price, step: '0.001' %></td>
        <td><input type="number" <%= form.number_field :fpa %></td>
        <td><input size="13" <%= form.text_field :familys %></td>
        <td><input size="13" <%= form.text_field :monadaMe %></td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
  </thead>
</table>
```

the bug i notices is that on windows 10 Google Chrome working fine but as ubuntu 19.10 mozila have the following problem at the same laptop 
So there must be a way to auto-size in css ? i dont know much about html and css so maybe this is something simple

***UPDATE*** 
still nothing
firefox vs chromium

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should try by including the following viewport element for making it responsive

````
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">```
</head>
````